# Why mongorestore always returning the error that directory not found even with correct file path?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I want to import some data in mongoDb database's collection. That collection already have some data and i want to import some more data into it. So for that i am using this command

```
mongorestore --drop -d local-db -c users /Documents/cwc/mongo-backups/Users.bson
```

but this command is always returning this error

```
Failed: mongorestore target '/Documents/cwc/mongo-backups/Users.bson' invalid: stat /Documents/cwc/mongo-backups/Users.bson: no such file or directory
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: "That collection already have some data and i want to import some more data into it." - why do you specify `--drop` in this case? Existing data will be dropped.

Comment: Is the file really `/Documents/cwc/mongo-backups/Users.bson` or is it at the relative directory position of `Documents/cwc/mongo-backups/Users.bson`?